# How to organize an app-engine application

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to create a directory structure like the following.  How can I get the account.py and game.py to handle the requests that go to  \account\ and \game\  respectfully.  All the app-engine examples I have seen have all the logic in on main.py that handle all urls.

```
app\account\
           \account.py
   \game\
        \ game.py
   \static\css
          \js
          \images
   \app.yaml
   \main.py
```

I tried the following in app.yaml  but it didn't work

```
application: mefirst
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:

- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /account
  script: account.py

- url: .*
  script: main.py
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [MVCEngine](http://code.google.com/p/gae-mvc-engine/), a framework for AppEngine that provides a Ruby on Rails-like structure for building apps. It may or may not be overkill for what you are looking to do, but if you take a look in the main project file, MVCEngine.py, you should be able to see how it goes about providing for a project directory structure somewhat like you want. It's not too difficult.

Answer (score 11):

You need the following in your `app.yaml`:

```
- url: /account
  script: account/account.py

- url: /game
  script: game/game.py

- url: .*
  script: main.py
```

BTW, I suggest you try to forget backslashes (characters like this: \ ) -- think *normal* slashes (characters like this: / ).  Backslashes are a Windows anomaly (and mostly unneeded even there -- Python will happily accept normal slashes in lieu of backslashes in filepaths), not used as path separators in URLs nor on Unix-y operating systems (including Linux and MacOSX).  I mention this because you speak of "requests that go to \account\ and \game\ respectfully" and there are no such things -- no request goes to a path with backslashes, it will always be *forward* slashes.

Comment: this will throw an error is appengine with threadsafe set to true

Comment: @DanielF yes, GAE has changed a lot in the 6 years since I wrote this answer -- in particular the "script" attribute must now indicate (in the python27 runtime) NOT a script, but rather a WSGI app (very unfortunate design decision, to overload "script" this way rather than introducing a new attribute name!), with dots, not slashes, etc, etc. But, with runtime "python" (as in the original question), threadsafe is NOT accepted anyway, etc, etc).